# Как передать функцию в качестве параметра в другую функцию на С++?

Tags: c++

Приведите пожалуйста простой пример

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот простейший пример. Надо в качестве параметра передавать указатель на функцию. Тема указателей на функцию довольно сложная. Про нее можно почитать в K&R, там достаточно подробно описано.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int f1 (int a) {
    cout << "f1: " << a << endl;
    return a*2;
}

void f2 (int (*ff) (int), int a) {
    int i = ff (a);
    cout << "f2: " << i << endl;

}

int main() {
    f2(f1, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

g++ test.cpp -o prog

./prog

f1: 5

f2: 10

Comment: mikillskegg большое спасибо, теперь я всё понял)